# GCD add block into a serial queue after state changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Recently I encounter a problem using GCD. Here are some code snippet:

```
static dispatch_queue_t queue() {
    static dispatch_queue_t sl_queue;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sl_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.somnus.xxx", NULL);
    });

    return sl_queue;
}

- (void)test
{
        while (self.state != finished)
        {
            //wait for finish
        }

        dispatch_async(queue(), ^{

                self.state = processing;


            void (^onFinish)(void) = 0;
            onFinish = ^(void){
                self.state = finished; 
            };

            [someObj doSomethingWithFinishBlock:onFinish];

        });
}
```

I want to make sure that every time when test() method add the block into the queue, the state is finished. In other words, when test invoked, check the state, if you find that the state is processing, wait for it changing to finished, then execute dispatch_async().

How could I implement this, thanks for any help!

EDIT:

doSomethingWithFinishBlock is a asynchronous function, I don't know when the onFinish Block will be enqueued

Comment: Is `doSomethingWithFinishBlock` asynchronous function?

Comment: @Cy-4AH Yes, doSomethingWithFinishBlock is a asyncrhonous function

Answer (score 2):

This is typically done with a `dispatch_semaphore`. Something along these lines:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) dispatch_semaphore_t sem;

// ... At some point you must initialize it to 1
// this essentially creates a pool of 1 token to share.
self.sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);

- (void)test
{
    // Checkout a token from the pool (there's only one)
    // block until I can get get. You could also timeout, which can be useful.
    dispatch_semphore_wait(self.sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    // Do a weak-self dance here if you need one. You may not in your example.
    dispatch_async(queue(), ^{
        dispatch_block_t onFinish = ^{
            // Return the token to the pool
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.sem)
        };

        [someObj doSomethingWithFinishBlock:onFinish];
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL` in your dispatch_queue_create("com.somnus.xxx", NULL);

Then you wouldn't have to do

> ```
>     while (self.state != finished)
>     {
>         //wait for finish
>     }
> ```

as the blocks are enqueued and executing one after the other.

Blocks exist so you don't have to actively wait. You don't have to have the state variable then.

The whole thing would just be:

```
static dispatch_queue_t queue() {
    static dispatch_queue_t sl_queue;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sl_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.somnus.xxx", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    });

    return sl_queue;
}

- (void)test
{
    dispatch_async(queue(), ^{
        [someObj doSomethingWithFinishBlock:nil];
    });
}
```

Comment: "You should use DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL in your dispatch_queue_create("com.somnus.xxx", NULL);" `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL` is defined as `NULL`

Comment: @Alistra, I want to make sure that the onFinish block enqueued before the next [someObj doSomethingWithFinishBlock:nil] block.

Comment: @newacct code readability is important, nobody knows what NULL means right away without docs

Comment: @Alistra: Well actually in a previous version of the SDK, when only serial queues could be created, the parameter was unused and the documentation specifically told you to pass `NULL`. Later, they added the ability to create concurrent queues and added the `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL` and `DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT`. The fact they had `NULL` there doesn't mean it was written poorly.

Comment: @Alistra: Anyway, the point is that your statements about "Then you wouldn't have to do ..." is incorrect or irrelevant because there is no difference between `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL` and `NULL`.